# Error encrypting files with Botan and Qt

Tags: c++, qt, cryptography, botan

I'am trying to use "Botan" to encrypt and decrypt files (AES 256). Integrating the library in Qt was done successfully. I followed many examples I found on the Internet like this [tutorial](http://grip.espace-win.org/doc/apps/botan/tutorial.pdf) but I got the following

```
error: 
class Botan::S2K' has no member named 'set_iterations'
```

I figured out that the Botan version for which the tutorial was created is outdated and that the version I'am using (1.10.5) is incompatible.

My question is:
Where can I find the tutorial for the new version? If none exists, where can I download the windows installer of the previous version (1.8 or 1.9)?

Here is my code so far: 
(Encryption)

```
string file = "...";
string fileEncrypted = "...";

Botan::LibraryInitializer init;

string passphrase = "password";
AutoSeeded_RNG rng;
S2K* s2k = get_s2k("PBKDF2(SHA-256)");
s2k->set_iterations(4049);

SecureVector<byte> key_and_IV = s2k->derive_key(48, passphrase).bits_of();
SymmetricKey key(key_and_IV, 32);
InitializationVector iv(key_and_IV +32, 16);

std::ifstream in(file, std::ios::binary);
std::ofstream out(fileEncrypted, std::ios::binary);

Pipe pipe(get_cipher("AES-256/CBC", key, iv,ENCRYPTION),new DataSink_Stream(out));
pipe.start_msg();
in >> pipe;
pipe.end_msg();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain version 1.9 from [here](http://m.icewalkers.com/jump.php?url=b4a9f467b52c0514468484727870884d&id=3740), but I am afraid you have two issues with the usage of the new version:

- `get_s2k()` is getting obsolete, and you should use `get_pbkdf()` instead.
- Instead of setting the iteration with the mutator method, you could pass the number of iterations to the derive_key in the version when using PBKDF instead of the deprecated S2k.

See the encrypt2 example of theirs for instance:

```
...
PKCS5_PBKDF2 pbkdf2(new HMAC(new SHA_160));

const u32bit PBKDF2_ITERATIONS = 8192;

SecureVector<byte> salt(8);
rng.randomize(&salt[0], salt.size());

SecureVector<byte> master_key = pbkdf2.derive_key(48, passphrase,
                                                 &salt[0], salt.size(),
                                                 PBKDF2_ITERATIONS).bits_of()
...
```

You could check out further examples for details in the `doc/examples` folder once you fetch their release and unpack it.

Comment: thx for the Answer. 
I followed the encrypt2 example and got my program to build but it crushes when I run It! I guess the Botan integration into Qt wasn't error free after all.

Comment: I ended up using the source code from this site: http://voidrealms.com/index.php?r=source/view&id=1
It uses an amalgamation build of Botan and works perfectly with Qt 5.2 (just need to change the depricated toAscii() function in toLatin1())